# conversion functions using create or replace function for in to cm

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

whats the best way to write conversion functions?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inches_to_centimeters(inches NUMERIC) RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN 1 inch = 1 * 2.54, 
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I'd try `RETURN inches * 2.54;`.

Answer (score 0):

When asking for the "best way", a `language sql` function is more efficient in this case.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inches_to_centimeters(inches NUMERIC) 
  RETURNS NUMERIC 
AS $$
  select inches * 2.54;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql
immutable;
```

Because the function can be defined as `immutable` it will (in most cases) be "inlined" into the calling SQL statement, so that there is no overhead at all. Calling a PL/pgSQL function has some overhead though, so if that is called many times in a large result, this might make a difference.

---

In your PL/pgSQL code you would need to use the following RETURN expression though:

```
RETURN inches * 2.54; --<< ; at the end, not a comma
```